# Does IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL support SSL with algorithm SHA2-2048?

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, sha2

I just finish the my Delphi application upgrade to XE3 with Indy 10.6 and now needs support HTTPS protocol with SHA2-2048 cert.
But I could not find any options for this algorithm and cert size.

I would like to know if Indy/OpenSSL would handle this algorithm automatically or need special configuration in source?
Many thanks!!

Comment: Do you have a link to SHA2-2048? - "SHA2, not often used for now, is the successor of SHA1 and gathered 4 kinds of hash functions: SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512" [link](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/sha256.html)

Comment: SHA2 was added to OpenSSL in 0.9.8o and 1.0.0a.  I have no clue what SHA2-2048 is, though.  Maybe you are thinking of a 2048-bit RSA key for one of the SHA2 hashes, like SHA256?  A Google search shows examples of that combination when generating CSRs on the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the explanation.

Below is cert information:

---

Signature Algorithm : sha256RSA

Public Key : RSA (2048bits)

Thumbprint Algorithm: sha1

---

I tried to load this cert in the Delphi application but got "Could not load the root certificate" error. But it worked with 1024bits cert.

Is it related to OpenSSL library?